# How to pass REQUEST_URI to function

Tags: urls, user-registration

I'm trying to build a custom URL with error messages at user registrations, e.g.: `?invalid_username=1` or `?email_exists=1`. I am able to build the front part of the URL manually/statically, with the line `$redirect_url = get_bloginfo('url') . '/register';`.

However, sometimes users call the registration site as `/register/?redirect_to=....` and I would like to **keep** the `?redirect_to` argument when adding the (error) arguments.

I tried replacing that line with `$redirect_url = get_bloginfo('url') . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` but apparently this does give me the `REQUEST_URI` from the wp-login: `mydomain.com/wp-login.php?action=register&email_exists=1`

Here's the full code:

```
add_action('register_post', 'register_fail_redirect', 99, 3);

function register_fail_redirect( $sanitized_user_login, $user_email, $errors ){
    //this line is copied from register_new_user function of wp-login.php
    $errors = apply_filters( 'registration_errors', $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email );
    //this if check is copied from register_new_user function of wp-login.php
    if ( $errors->get_error_code() ){

     //setup the custom URL for redirection
    $redirect_url = get_bloginfo('url') . '/register'; // <-- THIS works 
    // BUT I want $redirect_url to be the URL that was called when loading the site


    //add error codes to custom redirection URL one by one
        foreach ( $errors->errors as $e => $m ){
            $redirect_url = add_query_arg( $e, '1', $redirect_url );     
        }
        //add finally, redirect to your custom page with all errors in attributes
        wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit;   
    }
}
```

Appreciate your input!

Comment: Why don't you use [`registration_errors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/) filter to set up your custom error messages?

Comment: how would this solve my problem?